# Having hard time getting my public key to work

Tags: shell-script, scp

I'm using scp to send from a shared Hostgator site to Adrive's scp server.

I created a private and public key with puttygen.exe. First time, I put in my password for the passphrase. Second time, I did not put in a passphrase.

I uploaded the text for the public key to Adrive's website for both keys created. I also uploaded the private key to the Hostgator's

In both cases, I am getting prompted with this:

```
server [~/.ssh]# scp -i ~/.ssh/sss.ppk  ~/backups/zips/backup_2015_11_26.tgz user@scp.adrive.com:.
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/sss.ppk':
```

I enter in the password that I put for a passphrase and it just prompts me again. I tried this with the key that has a password and the one that does not.

I am not able to get past this part. I get prompted 3 times and then it asks me for the password for scp.

I want to use this in a script I wrote so that I can set a cron job to automate the backup.

When I do uname -or I am given this:

> 3.12.35.1418868451 GNU/Linux

Comment: Did you follow the instruction for translating the `putty` public key into the `ssh` (one-liner) format for `authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scp` is part of `openssh` and it does not support PuTTY key format (and current version suffers with "asking for a passphrase regardless the input).

You can convert the key from PPK format using [puttygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use/2224204#2224204) (Conversions -> Export OpenSSH), or simply create a new key in openssh format using `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The new key also store to the `authorized_keys`, but then it should work for you just fine.